# Make a button play a sound in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback

I am trying to make an app that when you touch a button (actually a .png image that I imported) a sound plays. Does anybody know how to do this? I am using xcode 4.5.2

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your audio file name" ofType:@"wav"]];
AVAudioPlayer *click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil];
[click play];
```

Write this code on action of your button click.Also Add AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h and AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h frameworks to your class.

Comment: It gives me the following errors at NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                                                                  pathForResource:@"Bazingas" ofType:@"m4a"]]; it says "Initializer Element is not compile time-consistant                                            On this line of code AVAudioPlayer *click  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile  error:nil]; it gives the following error "Use of undeclared identifier 'AVAudioPlayer'" Also "Unknown type name 'AVAudioPlayer"

Comment: add all frameworks that i told you to add from targets and make sure you have a audio file.Please flag up the comment it will also increase your points...Enjoy!!

Comment: Sorry Im really new to this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

[Youtube Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TycW9dYuK9A) explaining the full source code to make a soundboard application. However, next time you post a question you should aim to make it specific to a single problem that you have come across. Stack Overflow isn't your personal research assistant, a simple search on google for "soundboard app tutorial" would turn up plenty of results on showing you how to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can set button touchevent to play